# Problem: chances of an event occurring multiple times in N number of samples.

Tags: probability, statistics, game-theory, random

I have this problem that I am trying to solve:

There is an event with a **1.83%** chance or ~**0.0183** probability of occurring. There is also a score counter that starts with a score of **100**. Samples (or cycles) are run with a **100-1.83=98.17%** chance of the event NOT occurring. Every sample where the event doesn't occur scores you **+1**. When the event occurs, it scores you **-31** from the total score.

My question is, considering that these events can take place multiple times, how would one estimate the chance or probability of the score being >= 0 after **100**, **200**, **500** or **N** number of samples? A step by step explanation would be very appreciated if possible!

Comment: Here is a start to how you could figure it out for 100 samples. Note that the special event would need to happen at least $7$ times in order to give you a score less than $0$ in the end. So you can find $P(X \lt 6)$ for the binomial distribution with $n=100, p=0.0183$ where X represents the number of special events occurring.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I have simulated binomial distribution graph in Matlab and approximated the probability for that!